# Grails no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type

Tags: grails

I'm trying to upload file to my grails controller and then calling external service using the uploaded file. Here is my controller code:

```
  def detect() {
        def f = request.getFile('img')
        if (f.empty) {
            respond 'Image cannot be empty'     
            return
        }
        def rest=new RestBuilder()
        def resp = rest.post(...)
        respond resp.json
    }
```

but I got the following exception:

```
| Error 2015-02-26 17:14:27,102 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - HttpMessageNotWritableException occurred when processing request: [POST] /Twins/detection/detect
Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]
```

what is wrong with this code?

Comment: show your form as well

Comment: I'm using postman  form-data with img param as file

Comment: try replacing `respond` with `render`

Comment: The problem is in the first line. I replaced it and didn't work.

Comment: show your gsp-form, if you are sure that the exception occurs in `request.getFile('img')`

Comment: This is a webservice not an html form so I'm using postman as I told you before.

Comment: how this postman is sending the request? as a multi-part entity? what is the 'encoding'-header?